# Django-registration not recognizing urls.py accounts page?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to setup django-registration and it is not recognizing the URLs. I get Error 404 when I visit http://localhost:8000/accounts/

```
    Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/

Using the URLconf defined in namekeepr.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:


    ^pk/$
    ^pk/index/$
    ^admin/
    ^accounts/ ^activate/complete/$ [name='registration_activation_complete']
    ^accounts/ ^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$ [name='registration_activate']
    ^accounts/ ^register/$ [name='registration_register']
    ^accounts/ ^register/complete/$ [name='registration_complete']
    ^accounts/ ^register/closed/$ [name='registration_disallowed']
    ^accounts/ ^login/$ [name='auth_login']
    ^accounts/ ^logout/$ [name='auth_logout']
    ^accounts/ ^password/change/$ [name='auth_password_change']
    ^accounts/ ^password/change/done/$ [name='auth_password_change_done']
    ^accounts/ ^password/reset/$ [name='auth_password_reset']
    ^accounts/ ^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$ [name='auth_password_reset_confirm']
    ^accounts/ ^password/reset/complete/$ [name='auth_password_reset_complete']
    ^accounts/ ^password/reset/done/$ [name='auth_password_reset_done']
    ^admin/
    ^accounts/profile/$
    ^accounts/password_reset/$
    ^accounts/password_reset_done/$
    ^accounts/password_change/$
    ^accounts/password_change_done/$

The current URL, accounts/, didn't match any of these.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to http://localhost:8000/accounts/ with a slash on the end.  That is the 'regular' django url, usually it would redirect to this but it is not for some reason.... but before you try to solve *that* problem, should make sure it works this way.

Comment: it looks like you don't have an url defined for just ^accounts/?

Comment: hmm... well I used     (r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')), in the master application urls.py to include the django-registration urls.py. am I supposed to do it differently? is it not passing through correctly?

Comment: Ah!  Ok in your registration.urls, you still need an url with a path of ('^$').  It is including your registration.urls at /accounts, but they all involve additional characters (for example, a registration.url with the path ^somewhere is mapped to /accounts/somewhere.  You don't have anything JUST for /accounts/.

Answer (score 1):

based on the server response, you have not defined a url for `^/accounts/$` (the root of accounts)